# Use \ae ligature in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, ligatures

I have a reference containing a name: `Hornbaek`. The author's used a ligature when writing their name. The citation uses `Hornb\aek`, which doesn't work in the bibliography, but does work in text. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Rasmussen:2012:SIR:2207676.2207781,
 author = {Rasmussen, Majken K. and Pedersen, Esben W. and Petersen, Marianne G. and Hornb\aek, Kasper},
 title = {Shape-changing interfaces: a review of the design space and open research questions},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the SIGCHI Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Here's a ligature: \ae

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

This doesn't work - it gives this error:

> > ! Undefined control sequence.
> >     l.5   Hornb\aek

but if the `\ae` are removed from the citation, the correct ligature is displayed in the body of the document (so the `\ae` is right, just not in the citation). I attempted wrapping the command in `{..}`:

```
author = {... Hornb{\ae}k, Kasper},
```

but this gave me the same error. If I remove `\ae` from the citation, though, I don't get the ligature inserted for me.

**How can I use an explicit ligature in a bibliographic reference?**

Comment: `Hornb{\ae}k` will work

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes's suggestion *should* work, but if it doesn't (as you said), try `Hornb\ae k` instead -- `\aek` is certainly not a (standard) macro.

Comment: The reason why `{\ae}` gave you the same error is that you residual files left over from the failed compile.  Delete the .aux and .bbl file and then recompile.  cc: @SeanAllred

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes :( and I didn't clean the build files while making the MWE, either... removing residuals and re-building with `{\ae}` worked. Thanks.

Comment: Note that Danish æ is a character on its own, rather than a ligature.